# I cannot access phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I tried to set up a password on the phpmyadmin interface.
So I changed a parameter in config.inc.php : $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = FALSE. But since this change I have this error message which appears:

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I speak very little French. I believe it says something along the lines of "PHPMyAdmin cannot connect to MySQL" Could you translate the errormessage for non-French speaking users?

Comment: @Sevvlor phpMyAdmin cant acces to MySql, the server refused this connection. Please verify values of host, username and password in your configuration and be sure they are corresponding to informations provided by server administrator.

Comment: Connection not possible: incorrect settings.
PhpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server regected the connection. Please check the host, username, and password values in your configuration and make sure they match the information provided by the MySql server administrator

Comment: you have to change settings in your configuration file. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276538/phpmyadmin-cant-connect-invalid-setings-ever-since-i-added-a-root-passwor` `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883163/phpmyadmin-cannot-connect-to-mysql-server`

Comment: First and most obviously; do you have a password for your user? By setting that to false, you're disallowing users without a password to connect (also, the default is false anyway).