# mysql 5.6 - mysql command prompt no longer working and service still running

Tags: php, mysql, adminer

Windows 8.1 - mySql 5.6 This is a strange one: I went into command prompt entered: mysql -uroot as usual and got back: 'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I went looking for mysql.exe and it is just gone, not in trash or any where else... just gone. The service mysql56 is running and I can access the database with adminer and PHP.

My question is: can I extract another zip and copy the mysql.exe to C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL (I think that's where is should be) to get back the command prompt access?

The only thing that has really changed is that I downloaded adminer management tool and adminer editor to use since the new versions of phpmyadmin have tanked and cannot run past a timeout error. I don't see how or why adminer would have snarfed the mysql executable anyway.

Thanks for any help ... did search here and else where but found nothing resolve my question.

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920136/mysql-is-not-recognised-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-b)? Also, have you tried just reinstalling mysql? That might fix the problem too and would be more reliable than just copying the binary from a zip file.

Comment: If I install again I'll have two versions mysql databases. If I get rid of the one that's running I loose the tables and data or have to re create them.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the link to the post Mike. It provided a good hint. What appears to have happened -something had it's way with my environment path and windows weak search could not find  C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysql.exe. I'll spiff up my environment variable and should be good to go. Thanks again.

Comment: OK, due to this answer I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate