# Is it possible to access wamp mysql database from another computer using cmd?

Tags: mysql, wamp

I can connect to the localhost and phpmyadmin using another computer but I was wondering if I can do something like 'mysql -u root -p' in cmd using another computer to access the database from another computer. I'm using wamp server 2.5

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access.
You have to comment
`bind-address = 127.0.0.1`
in **my.conf** file.
Then restart MySQL.
login using
`mysql -h<your-system-ip> -uroot -p`

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie. Do I have to install wamp on the other PC? 'mysql' isn't recognized as a command in cmd.

Comment: No need of installing wamp on another PC. You can access mysql directly from cmd prompt. To configure it, please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920136/mysql-is-not-recognised-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-b)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

But you have to do it using a MySQL user account that is allowed to connect from another ip/domain.

A MySQL user account is made up of 2 parts, if you have seen any errors while connecting you may have seen someting like this `'root'@'localhost'`, they are the 2 parts.

The first part `'root'` is the userid and the second part `'localhost'` is the ip/domain the `'root'` is connecting from. You have to create an account *(best not to let `root` be used from anywhere!!!!!)* that is allowed to connect from your other ip address, or you can use `%` to indicate `from anywhere`

> Following shamlessly ripped of from that [MySQL Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-users.html)
>
> Its a good place to start

```
shell> mysql --user=root mysql
```

If you have assigned a password to the root account, you must also supply a --password or -p option.

After connecting to the server as root, you can add new accounts. The following example uses CREATE USER and GRANT statements to set up four accounts:

Setup shadow allowed access from localhost only

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'shadow'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Setup shadow allowed access from a specific ip address only

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'shadow'@'192.168.1.100' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'%'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Setup shadow allowed access from anywhere

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'shadow'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'%'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

The accounts created by those statements have the following properties:

Two accounts have a user name of monty and a password of some_pass. Both are superuser accounts with full privileges to do anything. The 'shadow'@'localhost' account can be used only when connecting from the local host. The 'shadow'@'%' account uses the '%' wildcard for the host part, so it can be used to connect from any host.

The 'shadow'@'localhost' account **is necessary if** there is an anonymous-user account for localhost. Without the 'shadow'@'localhost' account, that anonymous-user account takes precedence when monty connects from the local host and monty is treated as an anonymous user. The reason for this is that the anonymous-user account has a more specific Host column value than the 'shadow'@'%' account and thus comes earlier in the user table sort order. (user table sorting is discussed in Section 6.2.4, “Access Control, Stage 1: Connection Verification”.)

> You may want to consider not GRANTing super user access to accounts that can connect from a machine other that the PC running MYSQL for obvious reasons.